# Bokeh: Handling callbacks for unknown (at compile-time) number of buttons

Tags: python, button, callback, bokeh

I've created multiple buttons at runtime and stored them in a list.

```
keys = []
keys.append(Button(label="-- Parent --"))
for key in node_obj.children.keys():
    keys.append(Button(label=key))
```

Note that the number of children of `node_obj` may vary, so the number of buttons is not always the same. I'm trying to create callbacks for all the buttons and did it like this:

```
def test_fn(button): 
    print(button.label)

for button in keys:
    button.on_click(lambda : test_fn(button))
```

but it always prints the label of the last button in the list. How can I modify it such that the label of the button that was clicked is printed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a result of the way Python works. When the lambda is actually executed it uses the value of `button` from the outer scope—which is the last value of the loop. You will need to use the standard library `functools.partial` function to "bake in" each different button ahead of time:

```
from functools import partial

def test_fn(button): 
    print(button.label)

for button in keys:
    button.on_click(partial(test_fn, button=button))
```